# C# save WinSCP stream to Azure Blob Storage Error: Offsets with value of non-zero are not supported

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to save a file downloaded from an SFTP site using the WinSCP .NET library, and then save it Azure Blob storage.  I don't want to use `CloudBlobContainer` as it is deprecated.  I keep getting the error message:

> Offsets with value of non-zero are not supported
> when executing .... `await blobClient.UploadAsync`

```
using WinSCP;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =
    blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containername);
BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    string remotePath = "/myfile.zip";
    using (System.IO.Stream stream = session.GetFile(remotePath, transferOptions))
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream,new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/zip"
        }
    );
};
```

I am able to write the stream to disk.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the WinSCP .NET assembly stream implementation in earlier releases was not compatible with Azure Blob API.

This [is solved in WinSCP 6.1](https://winscp.net/tracker/2181).
Please upgrade.

---

Old answer, before the fix was released: You can work it around by copying the SFTP file to temporary in-memory buffer:

```
using (var stream = session.GetFile(remotePath))
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/zip"
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I will do the copy for now, and wait till the release is stabilized :)

Comment: @laney Stable WinSCP 6.1 with the fix has been released already.